# VSTGUI 4.0 - error C2664: 'std::make_pair'

Tags: c++, vst

I'm trying to make a very simple gui for a vst plugin using vstgui 4.0. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express. When I build it, I'm getting an error from one of the sdk files. The error is:

```
error C2664: 'std::make_pair' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const VSTGUI::CViewAttributeID' to 'VSTGUI::CViewAttributeID &&' c:\sdks\vst3 sdk\vstgui4\vstgui\lib\cview.cpp 691 1 VST
```

Its coming from the 'attributes.insert...' line in cview.cpp:

```
bool CView::setAttribute (const CViewAttributeID id, const int32_t inSize, const void* inData)
{
    if (inData == 0 || inSize <= 0)
        return false;
    CViewAttributeConstIterator it = attributes.find (id);
    if (it != attributes.end ())
        it->second->updateData (inSize, inData);
    else
        attributes.insert (std::make_pair<CViewAttributeID, CViewAttributeEntry*> (id, new CViewAttributeEntry (inSize, inData)));
    return true;
}
```

What can I do to fix this? Is there some way I'm supposed to suppress this error?

Comment: Replace `std::make_pair` with `std::pair`.

Comment: So is this a bug in the sdk? I'm not supposed to modify anything in this file.

Comment: No, it's strictly a bug between keyboard and chair (not necessarily *your* chair). Don't specify function template arguments that are meant to be deduced. It was always wrong to do so, but going from C++03 to C++11 introduced a breaking change in `make_pair` that would surface this error. It's a "deserves to be broken" kind of breaking change.

Comment: Please [watch this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Don-t-Help-the-Compiler) before resuming this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a breaking change in `make_pair` when used incorrectly in C++11: if you specify argument types, it means something different in C++11 than in C++03.

To fix this, change `std::make_pair` that specifies argument types to `std::pair` and leave everything else alone.

Alternatively, remove the type arguments to `make_pair`, as you should basically never pass them.  This can, however, change how things work if the old code was doimg something quirky (in the above case it is safe I think).

The first solution will, however, mimic C++03s behavior in C++11 closer, in case they did something strange, so is safest.

`std::make_pair` without `<>` after them you should leave alone.

This breaking change is related to perfect forwarding efficiency improvements in C++11 and support for `move` only types.